# Get XML Tag in current hierarchy

Tags: c#

I would like take all the `Photo` tag that are inside the current `Property` tag xml.

**XML**

```
<Properties>
    <Property>
        <Photos>
            <Photo>
            </Photo>
        </Photos>
    </Property>
    <Property>
        <Photos>
            <Photo>
            </Photo>
        </Photos>
    </Property>
    <Property>
        <Photos>
            <Photo>
            </Photo>
        </Photos>
    </Property>
</Properties>
```

**Code**

```
xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Property");
for (int i = 0; i < xmlnode.Count - 1; i++)
{
    XmlNodeList xmlNode2;                            
    xmlNode2 = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Photo");

    // I wanna get all the Photo tag that are inside the current Property tag
    for (int j = 0; j < xmlNode2.Count - 1; j++)
    {
        // Get the total of tags called Photo in my XML      
    }
}
```

But in my code, I'm getting the total of `Photos` tag in all `XML` file, not in the current `Property` tag.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice you code to select all `Property` elements is identical to your code to get `Photo` elements.

Instead using indexes, you could rely on XPath to process your XML document, like this:

```
// Starting XPath expression with a slash means: "starting at document element"
foreach (XmlElement property in xmldoc.SelectNodes("/Properties/Property"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Property");

    // Without a starting slash, you'll use current node context
    foreach (XmlElement photo in property.SelectNodes("Photos/Photo"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\tPhoto");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Property
    Photo
Property
    Photo
Property
    Photo
```

Comment: I tried with your XML sample file and works. Are you sure you used same XML structure? You probably knows, but XML operations are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public void ProcessPhotos() {
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("<path to your xml file");
    foreach(XElement xProperty in xDoc.Descendants("Property")) {
        // goes through all Property xml elements
        foreach(XElement xPhoto in xProperty.Descendants("Photo")) {
            // and process all photos in current Property element
        }
    }
}
```